# eSATA PCIe card, HotSwap, and errors

Tags: backup, pci-express, esata, safely-remove-hardware

I've been using HotSwap (http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm) to remove HDDs connected to an eSATA PCIe card. These drives are for backups.

The problem is that every time I use HotSwap to eject a device I get an error in Windows event logs.  I'm trying to use this for backups and so seeing an error every time a drive is ejected sorta undermines my confidence in the validity of the backups.

Comment: Interesting question.  Welcome to Superuser.  You should take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: Just because windows logs an error does not mean there is anything wrong with the hardware. Please post the full error message that gets logged.

Comment: It's a matter of OS settings. Any SATA adapters can be configured to be seen as 'removable', even the onboard-connected SATA drives.